# What is the Difference between javascript apply() method and call() method

Tags: javascript

I have been using JavaScript Apply() method to Pass a callback function to a function as :

```
fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray]);
```

Now i found the Call() method and am trying to understand what is the difference , is it just the wey i pass on the arguments?!!

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

What is the difference between them